# IP testing tool similar to wireshark website

Tags: ipv6, website, wireshark, ipv4

I am looking to implement a tool similar to the one linked below on my personal server/website what are the steps I would need to get started?

```
http://www.wireshark.org/tools/v46status.html
```

I understand that I will need two seperate domains for example: (ipv4.mywebsite.com and ipv6.mywebsite.com) from which I will serve the images.  What would be the next step?

Comment: One would need to write a book to explain all of the things you'll need to know to implement this. As asked, this question is **far** too broad. Start working on things, and then come back with specific, well-scoped, well-researched questions and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: You can use existing services that do this like http://www.ipv6test.nl/demosource.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it using PHP on your server:

```
function is_ipv6() {
    $ipv4_mapped_ipv6 = strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "::ffff:");
    return (strpos($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ":") !== FALSE) &&
           ($ipv4_mapped_ipv6 === FALSE || $ipv4_mapped_ipv6 != 0);
}
```

It's a modified version of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13677565